# Formatting issues with glossaries in multiple file document

Tags: glossaries, texmaker, glossaries-extra

I'm currently writing my thesis with TexMaker and I also use the glossaries(-extra) package for my abbreviations. In general everythin works fine, but I'm struggeling with some formatting.
First of all this is my list of abbreviations:
[image]

Now I would like the abbreviations to be nowmal text instead of italic. In the text the abbreviations also appear in italic:

[image]

I tried to change the font style with these approaches: [(1)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254515/how-to-use-glossaries-defglsentryfmt-to-typeset-the-first-occurrance-of-an-ent/254657), [(2)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238318/how-to-replace-defglsdisplayfirst-and-defglsdisplay-with-glossaries-update), [(3)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303888/different-formatting-for-acronyms-and-glossary-entries)
but unfortunately it didn't work out for me..
This is what i tried so far:

[image]

**Update**

Here is a minimal working example:

Masterfile:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage,german,a4paper,twoside = false]{scrbook}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
% EINGEBUNDENE PAKETE
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %  Satztrennung, Inhaltsverzeichnis Umlaute nach deutscher Norm
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % korrekte Satztrennung und beliebige Zeichensetzung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % um nicht ASCI Zeichen einfügen zu können
\usepackage[centertags, nosumlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext} % for \text macro
\usepackage{array}   % for \newcolumntype macro
\usepackage{multirow} % for merged cells
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{calc}
%\usepackage{thumbpdf}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
%Meine Packages
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrhack}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} % Gliederungstiefe bis zu 5 (subsubsection)
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} % Inhaltsverzeichnis bis auf 5 Gliederungsebenen

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
% HYPERLINKS
\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksnumbered,colorlinks]{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{colorlinks=false,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarks=true}
\hypersetup{linkcolor = black,anchorcolor = blue,citecolor =
blue,filecolor = black,urlcolor = blue}


%===============% Symbol- und Abkürzungsverzeichnisoptionen %================%
\usepackage[nomain, toc]{glossaries-extra} 

\newglossary[gsg]{Formelzeichen}{gsi}{gso}{Formelzeichen}
\newglossary[alg]{Akronyme}{acr}{acn}{Abkuerzungsverzeichnis}

\makeglossaries 
\loadglsentries{Formelzeichen-Akronyme}
\renewcommand{\glspostdescription}{} 
%\defglsentryfmt[alg]{\textbf{#1}} 
%\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
%\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossnamefont}{textbf}

\newglossarystyle{Formelstyle}{% 
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}% 
    {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}lp{10cm}l}}% [l]= linksbündige longtable, 
                                                              %@{}= kein Abstand vor erster Spalte 
    {\end{longtable}}% 
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{% 
    \bfseries Symbol&\bfseries\descriptionname& 
    \bfseries Einheit\tabularnewline\endhead}% 
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}% 
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{% 
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} & 
    \glossentrydesc{##1} & \glossentrysymbol{##1}\tabularnewline 
  }% 
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{% evtl noch anpassen 
     & 
     \glssubentryitem{##2}% 
     \glstarget{##2}{\strut}\glossentrydesc{##2} & 
     ##3\tabularnewline 
  }% 
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{% 
    \ifglsnogroupskip\else & &\tabularnewline\fi}% 
} 

\newglossarystyle{Akronymstyle}{% 
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}% 
    {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}lp{10cm}l}}% [l]= linksbündige longtable, 
                                                              %@{}= kein Abstand vor erster Spalte 
    {\end{longtable}}% 
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{% 
    \bfseries Symbol&\bfseries\descriptionname& 
    \tabularnewline\endhead}% 
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}% 
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{% 
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} & 
    \glossentrydesc{##1} & \glossentrysymbol{##1}\tabularnewline 
  }% 
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{% evtl noch anpassen 
     & 
     \glssubentryitem{##2}% 
     \glstarget{##2}{\strut}\glossentrydesc{##2} & 
     ##3\tabularnewline 
  }% 
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{% 
    \ifglsnogroupskip\else & &\tabularnewline\fi}% 
} 

\defglsentryfmt[alg]{\textbf{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}}
%===============% Allgemeine Seitenstil-Optionen %================%
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} % Überschriften in Latex-Schriftart
\clearpairofpagestyles % Zurücksetzen der Seitenstile

%===============% Kopf- und Fußzeilenoptionen %================%
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt} %Kopfzeilenhöhe
\KOMAoptions{                   % Kopzeilen-Trennlinie sichtbar auch für plain
    headsepline = true,
    footsepline = true,
    plainheadsepline = true,
    plainfootsepline = true
    }

\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}
\ohead{Seite~\pagemark}%{Kopfzeile außen}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\parindent0em


%===============% Silbentrennungen %================%
\hyphenation{Schen-kel-pol-ma-schi-ne Kol-lek-tor-Dau-er-gleich-strom Sperr-schicht-tem-pe-ra-tur}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
% DECKBLATT
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty} \setcounter{chapter}{0}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}
\textbf{\Huge{Test document}}\\[5pt]
\vspace*{2cm}
{\Large Master-Thesis}\\
\vspace*{0.4cm}
von\\
\vspace*{0.3cm}
D Mark\\
\vspace*{0.1cm}
Matrikelnummer: 31111\\
\vspace*{1.5cm}
Referent: \\
\vspace*{0.1cm}
Korefferent: \\
\vspace*{1.5cm}
{\Large ...}\\
\vspace*{0.3cm}
{\large ....}\\
\vspace*{0.3cm}
{\large Test}\\

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

%===============% Inhalts-, Symbol- und Abkürzungsverzeichnis %================%

{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black} % Inhaltsverzeichnis bleibt schwarz
\tableofcontents
}
\cleardoublepage

\printglossary[type=Akronyme,title={Abkürzungsverzeichnis}, style=Akronymstyle]
\printglossary[type=Formelzeichen,title={Formelzeichen}, style=Formelstyle]

\cleardoublepage
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Textbeginn
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{1-Einleitung}

\end{document}
```

The 1-Einleitung.tex file:

```
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                  Einleitung
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\parindent}{2ex}

\chapter{Einleitung}

Here we have some text to test the abbreviations like \gls{PWM} \gls{SVM} \gls{PMSM}
```

and the Formelzeichen-Akronyme.tex file:

```
%===============% Formelzeichen %================%
%==============================================%

\newglossaryentry{ElektrLeitf}{name=\ensuremath{\sigma}, description={Elektrische Leitfähigkeit eines Materials}, symbol={\ensuremath{(\Omega m)^{-1}}}, type=Formelzeichen}

\newglossaryentry{CBertotti}{name=\ensuremath{C}, description={Konstante nach Bertotti}, symbol={}, type=Formelzeichen}


%===============% Abkürzungen %================%
%==============================================%

\newglossaryentry{PWM}{name=\ensuremath{PWM}, description={Pulsweitenmodulation}, type=Akronyme}

\newglossaryentry{PMSM}{name=\ensuremath{PMSM}, description={Permanenterregte Synchronmaschine}, type=Akronyme}


\newglossaryentry{SVM}{name=\ensuremath{SVM}, description={Raumzeigermodulation - engl. space vector modulation}, type=Akronyme}

%==============================================%
```

All files are in the same directory.

Can someone may help me to change the text style to normal text? Is the problem maybe that I am using multiple files?

Comment: Unless you provide some actual code that others can copy and test, you are probably not very likely to get any help

Comment: In other words: please prepare a complete self contained minimal working example that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the post!